# Google OAUTH refresh token downloaded as file

Tags: javascript

I try to get a refresh token with offline access for the google calendar.
I followed the docs, to get the code i used the function provided by google, my website then gets called with the redirect uri and the code param in it.

With this code I have to call
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
now with my parameters, when I tried to send a post request with an `XMLHttpRequest` I got an CORS error for some reason.

So I tried it like in the google docs with `form.submit()`, and this indeed gives me refresh token I want, but it is downloaded as a file (chrome).

My problem is that I dont know how to access this token now.

The function looks like this

```
function getToken(code) {
    var oauth2Endpoint = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';

    var form = document.createElement('form');
    form.setAttribute('method', 'POST');
    form.setAttribute('action', oauth2Endpoint);

    var params = {'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
                  'redirect_uri': 'https://www.xxyxyyx.io/aut.html',
                  'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
                  'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
                  'code': code,
                  'grant_type': 'authorization_code'
                };

    for (var p in params) {
      var input = document.createElement('input');
      input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
      input.setAttribute('name', p);
      input.setAttribute('value', params[p]);
      form.appendChild(input);
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
  }
```

is there a way to get the result from the `form.submit()`?

Comment: _"when I tried to send a post request with an XMLHttpRequest I got an CORS error for some reason"_ - that reason probably being that Google explicitly does not allow CORS for this endpoint, because you are supposed to call it from a server only. And that is because this endpoint gets your client secret passed as a parameter, which of course should never be exposed in publicly available client-side code.

Comment: So do I need to pass the code to my server, and then my server calls this endpoint to get the refresh token?